# Absolute positioned DIV hovers over other elements

Tags: html, css

I have two JSP pages that are just about identical.  Each page has an outer DIV that has the "position: relative" property/value.  Each page also has an inner DIV that has a "position: absolute" property/value.

On one page, the absolute positioned DIV doesn't hover over any other elements on the page - it just stops moving before moving over the other elements while I resize the window.

On the other page (which has the same exact outer DIV and inner DIV properties and values), the absolute positioned DIV DOES hover over other elements on the page as I resize the window.

Any thoughts on why this could be happening?  I ultimately want both absolute positioned DIVs to NOT hover over any other elements on the page...

Here's a snippet of the markup and css involved...

**CSS**
`.BODY_OUTLINE {`
`position: relative;`
`border:2px outset white;`
`border-top: none;`
`font-style: normal;`
`margin: 0px;`
`margin-right:7em;`
`padding-top:0px;`
`FONT-FAMILY: arial, tahoma, verdana, sans-serif;`
`width:100%;`
`}`

**HTML**
`<DIV CLASS="BODY_OUTLINE">`
`...`
   `<DIV STYLE="border:10px outset gray; position:absolute; right:20%; top:20%;">`

Comment: This is for IE 8 specifically BTW

Comment: post the relevant html + css if you want an answer...

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without some markup and CSS.

Comment: Note: when posting code snippets, please don't post JSP code, but just its generated HTML/CSS as the webbrowser has retrieved which is all what counts in HTML/CSS issues.

Comment: Edited this post and provided sample markup and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements will always "hover over" other elements on the page if those elements themselves are not specifically constrained in such a way to prevent it. This is because `absolute` elements are out of flow (that is, they are ignored by other elements and they ignore most other elements themselves; a `relative` positioned parent being an exception).

The fact that you have one page that seems to behave as you want is probably by "accident." I cannot tell you the exact reason because you have only posted the code for the `BODY_OUTLINE` wrapper and the `absolute` div, but all the other items and css could be relevant to this problem as well, since, as I said above, the other elements have to be made to account for the absolutely positioned element through size, margins, its own positioning, or some such.

Comment: I thought that the typical behavior of absolute elements was out of flow so it's strange that one of the pages is NOT doing the hover over...I'll try to dig a little deeper to find out why...I think I'll also try to reformat the page such that I don't have to use absolute positioning...thanks.

Comment: I ended up re-positioning the whole page to avoid the use of absolute positioning all-together...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell since I have no idea of the other elements on the pages, but I'd try playing a bit with z-indexes on your divs:

```
.BODY_OUTLINE {
position: relative;
z-index:999; /* do this for all elements that have position absolute or relative */
}

<DIV STYLE="border:10px outset gray; position:absolute; right:20%; top:20%; z-index:1">
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment - I tried the z-index and read up on it a little bit but it didn't help with this problem in particular.  I ended up abandoning absolute position on the page all-together...